# Compiling Code on Linux Server Seems to Run Differently

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, emacs, makefile

I couldn't think of a good way to name this question, as the description of the issue is pretty lengthy.  Basically, the issue I'm having is, code that I wrote in Xcode on my mac isn't running the same after I upload to a linux server for my school.  I've never had this issue before.  Its not a syntax issue, which is something that I might run into (IE maybe I dont need to include a certain header file on Xcode that needs to be included to run on the linux server, so I get an error when I try to compile there), but its a logic error.  One specific if-else statement is evaluating entirely wrong.  It works correctly in Xcode, but with the same .cc file uploaded to the linux server and compiled with a makefile, it has a totally different result, using the same exact input that was used in Xcode.  I even open the .cc file with emacs after uploading to make sure none of the code has been altered from a botched upload, but nothing has changed at all.  This is very strange.  I've never ran into this sort of issue before.  I'd like to provide the code, but it might be entirely too long, so I need to break it down into a smaller example.  For now, I'd like to know if this is something anyone else has ever ran into.  The assignment deals with graph theory.  I'm typing in 'A' and 'B' to draw edges between two vertices.  You can see it works from the Xcode build, but not from the Linux build.

[image: Program Ran From Xcode Build In Terminal]
[image: Program Ran after Compiling on Linux Server and Being Ran]

Comment: Yes, other people have written code that compiles successfully but behaves differently on different systems.  This can happen when the program or compiler does not strictly conform to the standard.  Usually, the problem is with the program.  And this is the part where I tell you not to post the whole program, but to instead cut it down to a [mcve], and post that.

Comment: (Also and just as an aside, the singular of 'vertices' is 'vertex')

Comment: Thanks.  I actually knew this from previous math classes, I think my brain is just entirely scrambled right now trying to figure this out.

Comment: @JohnBollinger.  I'm finding it hard to narrow the code down to something fairly small.  I can cut a ton of it out, but to keep it functioning, it still requires quite a bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.  In Xcode, for some reason, I was inputting a character into a string like as 'cin >> string[0]' which worked fine, but this was causing the issue when compiling on the linux servers.  It wouldn't accept the array style input and I had to use 'cin >> string'